# "Not a uniquely defined name" when there is only one definition?

Tags: compiler-errors, cobol

Can there be any other reasons for the cobol compiler error message:

```
"TBBNR" was not a uniquely defined name.
The definition to be used could not be determined from the context.
The reference to the name was discarded.
```

than having the variable defined multiple times?

I have a small array from which I want to print correlating entries:

```
01  TABINHALTBRNR.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '77917982 02'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '01000046 09'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '29029435 10'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '39808565 11'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '44826590 12'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '34216875 13'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '87119697 15'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '54301143 16'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '55419988 17'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '72302437 18'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '81116613 21'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '62207726 24'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '01000024 25'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '26109788 28'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '90209055 70'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '98503184 71'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '98094032 80'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '66667777 99'.


   01  TABBRNR REDEFINES TABINHALTBRNR.
     05  FILLER    OCCURS 18.
       10  TBBNR          PIC X(8).
       10  FILLER         PIC X(1).
       10  TBRNR          PIC X(2).
```

But here when I'm actually trying to use a variable from the array I'm getting the error mentioned above:

```
PERFORM VARYING IX FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL IX > 25
       END-PERFORM
       IF IX < 26
          MOVE TBBNR(IX)       TO DSME-BBNREP
       END-IF
```

Now my issue is, the solution would be obvious if I had **TBBNR** defined anywhere else than in the array, but I actually do not have it defined anywhere else in my code! So can there be any other reasons for this error?

Comment: Is IX a uniquely defined name? DSME-BBNREP a uniquely defined name? Which data item was not a uniquely defined name? TBBNR?

Comment: Hi @APL, posting the full code might help.

Comment: It says that TBBNR was not uniquely defined, but it, like the others you mentioned, all only have one definition. Posting the entire code might be a bit much since the program does a lot more than just this.

Comment: Hi @APL, I've updated the message for IGYDS1266 code in my answer. Check if the field 'TBBNR' and the PROGRAM-ID have the same name.

Comment: Nope, my program sure isn't named "TBBNR" as well. I just tried playing around and using the other variable of the array "TBRNR" gives me the same error as in the main post. And I double sure don't have two names for my program either...

Comment: The compiler doesn't lie, you either have a typo somewhere, or there is copybook being pulled in with a variable that has the same name. Look at your compile listing and do a find on TBBNR it will be there twice.

Comment: Compile with symbol listing and inspect this, it should help you to see where the duplicate name is.

Comment: Which compiler and version?

Answer (score 2):

I tried compiling the code that you've showed & I did get the following errors during compilation.

```
IGYDS1266-E   The name "TBBNR" was used for an item that was not defined as a data-name.  References to this name may be
          resolved incorrectly.                                                                                     
IGYPS0037-S   "TBBNR" was not a uniquely defined name.  The definition to be used could not be determined from the context.
              The reference to the name was discarded.
```

Then, I came through the following message for `IGYDS1266` code.

```
Because the field and the PROGRAM-ID have the same
name, the following compile error occurs. In the
program output, the following error message is printed
all on one line.
IGYDS1266-E The name xxxxxxxx was used for an
item that was not defined as a data-name.
References to this name may be resolved
incorrectly.
User response: Follow these steps:
1. Make either of the following changes:
- Modify the value of the Program Name that is specified for the flow in the generation properties
file. 
- Rename and Refactor the field in the message.
2. Rerun the Generate Runtime Code wizard.
```

I took the second point from 1st step and renamed TBBNR to TUB. The compiler didn't throw an error after renaming.

Code:

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.                                  
PROGRAM-ID. TBBNR.                                        
DATA DIVISION.                                            
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                                  
01  TABINHALTBRNR.                                        
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '77917982 02'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '01000046 09'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '29029435 10'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '39808565 11'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '44826590 12'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '34216875 13'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '87119697 15'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '54301143 16'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '55419988 17'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '72302437 18'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '81116613 21'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '62207726 24'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '01000024 25'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '26109788 28'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '90209055 70'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '98503184 71'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '98094032 80'.
     05  FILLER             PIC X(11) VALUE '66667777 99'.
01  TABBRNR REDEFINES TABINHALTBRNR.                      
     05  TABLE1    OCCURS 18.                             
       10  TUB            PIC X(8).                       
       10  FILLER         PIC X(1).                       
       10  TBRNR          PIC X(2).                       
01  WS-HOLD                 PIC X(11).                    
01  IX                      PIC 9(2).                     
PROCEDURE DIVISION.                                       
    PERFORM VARYING IX FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL IX > 25          
           END-PERFORM.                                   
           IF IX < 26                                     
              MOVE TUB(IX)       TO WS-HOLD               
           DISPLAY WS-HOLD        
        END-IF.                   
 DISPLAY 'HELLO'                  
 STOP RUN.
```

Output:

```
********************************* TOP OF DATA **********************************
HELLO                                                                           
******************************** BOTTOM OF DATA ********************************
```

Comment: This is weird. Whereass my program doesn't have the same name as **any** variable used in it and therefore not giving me your first error, changing the variable "TBBNR" to for example "TABBNR" did the trick and it no longer gives me the error that it is not uniquely defined. I'd like to find out though why this is the case. TBBNR for sure is not defined anywhere else or even is used anywhere else in the code.

Comment: Hi @APL, are you sure PROGRAM-ID isn't TBBNR? The code which I've shown in my answer runs even if I use TBBNR as a data item, but with different PROGRAM-ID i.e., PROGRAM-ID. TABNR.

Comment: Definitly. It's named QSO218 as a matter of fact. But thank you for the help so far.

Answer (score 0):

The value given to PROGRAM-ID is a defined name, so can't be used elsewhere. Likewise for file handles.

Generate a compile-listing and search it for the defined name that is supposedly duplicated - you will find that it is.